# Custom Metric in Stackdriver with PHP Appengine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, stackdriver

I am developing a php appengine application. In some parts of the code I have some metrics i would like to save to be showed and analyzed in stackdriver monitoring.
To be clear i set an example:

> script.php is performing data manipulation, 10 times per minutes.  Each
>   time the script run it produce some statistics as, number of record
>   manipulated, time used to manipulate the records, number of errors.

How can i "send" this data to stackdriver (using php) to monitor how the script is performing using my metrics?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

To add custom metric to Stackdriver in php appengine, use the REST APIS:
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/